# React router dom show a component after user signs in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom to navigating inside by reactjs app.
My `app.js` looks like so:

```
return(
   <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
         <Route path="/signin" component={signin} />
         <SideBar />
         <Route path="/home" component={home} />
         <Route path="/user" component={user} />
         <Route path="/settings" component={settings} />
      </BrowserRouter>
   </div> 
);
```

My question is I want to show `<SideBar />` only if a user has already logged in. But as seen from the current code, it is displayed even in the `signin` page. What is the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: Autheniticate the  `signin` route

Comment: Render you Routes as `<Route component={RequireAuth(SideBar)} />`

Comment: This isn't duplicate of that question. Please note that there is no path to the SideBar component and it isn't a route. The sidebar will be present for home, user and settings as well after the user logs in.